# zsh: set option for a single command

Tags: zsh

Can I set a zsh option (like extendedglob) for a single command? Something like:

```
setopt extendedglob  param="${foo%%[0-9]##}"
```

With the command used above, I believe enclosing in `()` would not be a solution because the assignment of `param` would be lost, so I am excluding that as a solution. I also don't want to potentially clobber the environment by setting the option beforehand and then unsetting it afterwards (in the scenario that it was set already and then will be unset).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could be done in a conjunction of [`localoptions`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-LOCALOPTIONS) and [anonymous function](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-anonymous-functions).

```sh
local param='' foo='foo123'
() {
  setopt localoptions extendedglob
  param="${foo%%[0-9]##}"
}
echo $param $options[extendedglob] ;# ⇒ foo off
```

If we cannot use anonymous functions in certain version of zsh, we could give some throw-away name for it.

Comment: Thanks! (Bit ugly for zsh, though. You'd think they'd have a nicer way of doing it...)